# How I can show my android constrain layout chain icon hints, I did not show this feature in my layout. I am using android version 3.5.2

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In my layout, I did not show constraint layout hints. build.gradle

```
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView10"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView11"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView9"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call_24px" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView9"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView10"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_access_time_black_24dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="206dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView11"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView10"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView10"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView10"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_done" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How I can show hints icon in my layout.
[image: Here is my android studio XML layout image.]

**I want to show my layout like this image. I didn't show hints chain mode icon, remove icon etc**
[image: I want to hins like this Image]

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no property in chain or in constrain layout which helps you to show hint below image and you can simply achieve this  by taking three different textview below each image.

Ex :

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView10"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="150dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView11"
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView9"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView9"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call_24px" />


<TextView
android:id="@+id/txt1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView10"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView10"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, But I want to change my layout in the Design view. You can see my second image whare I indicate the icon.

Comment: all you want to shift into design view?